# why is Airtable API and Python not workinng?;

Tags: python-3.x, airtable

I am new to Python and APIs and I am trying to get some data from the API. More specifically I am trying to get some tables from a base. I am following this GitHub repository's instructions:
https://github.com/bayesimpact/airtable-python

So far I have created a virtual environment called *mypyth* and in there I have initiated a script called *get_data.py*

This is what my script looks like (I have written API KEY instead of my real api key:

```
import requests
from airtable import airtable
at = airtable.Airtable('appa3r2UUo4JxpjSv', 'API KEY')
at.get('Campaigns')
```

Now these are the commands I run on the console:

```
(mypyth) PS C:\Users\andri\PythonProjects\mypyth> py do_get_account.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "do_get_account.py", line 2, in <module>
    from airtable import airtable
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airtable'
(mypyth) PS C:\Users\andri\PythonProjects\mypyth>
```

Does anyone understand why I get this error? Perhaps there is a step I havent followed? Thanks in advace for any answer

Comment: Change the import to `import airtable`

Comment: @Frans I have tried it already but it doesnt work

Comment: Did you install airtable in your virtual environment? `pip install airtable`