# Why is airtable-python-wrapper not working?

Tags: python, python-requests, airtable

So I installed the package for the *airtable-python-wrapper* found on the github page https://github.com/gtalarico/airtable-python-wrapper/blob/master/README.md by inputting in my project folder:

```
pip install airtable-python-wrapper
```

Later on I wrote the following script :

```
from airtable import Airtable
from pprint import pprint


base_key = 'mykey'
table_name = 'MyBase'
myVar = Airtable(base_key, table_name)
print(myVar)
```

which when I run I get the error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Airtable' from 'airtable' (unknown location)
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Why does it not recognize the class *Airtable*? I am following the documentation, so I do not understand what the problem is. Thanks in advance

Comment: `pip install airtable-python.wrapper`, with a dot?

Comment: maybe it's the python version? Try to execute that script on Python 2 and 3

Comment: @Shinratensei thanks for the answer! why would you use a dot instread of - since the documentation suggests the command  *pip install airtable-python-wrapper* ?

Comment: exactly that's what I'm asking you, because in your question you've written it as I did. I suppose you just made a typo there while writing it and it's not in your code but still

Comment: @Shinratensei oh I am sorry, I  corrected it! How could I run a script with Python 2? Should I install Python 2?

Comment: Well you should be running it in python 2 if you execute it using the `python` command. To run it on python 3 you should use `python3`. I know some OSs on which it's the opposite, like Arch, where `python` executes python 3 and `python2`  executes python 2. Just try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is Airtable API and Python not workinng?;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55242843/why-is-airtable-api-and-python-not-workinng)

Answer (score 1):

Unless this was a bad build, this is likely caused by having your file or adjacent file named `airtable`:

#### Setup

```sh
❯ python -m venv .venv

❯ source ./.venv/bin/activate

.venv ❯ pip install airtable-python-wrapper
```

#### Tests

```sh
.venv ❯ echo "from airtable import Airtable; print(Airtable)" > test.py

.venv ❯ python test.py
<class 'airtable.airtable.Airtable'>

.venv ❯ echo "from airtable import Airtable; print(Airtable)" > airtable.py

.venv ❯ python airtable.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "airtable.py", line 1, in <module>
    from airtable import Airtable; print(Airtable)
  File "/Users/gui_talarico/dev/repos/gtalarico/test/project/airtable.py", line 1, in <module>
    from airtable import Airtable; print(Airtable)
ImportError: cannot import name 'Airtable' from 'airtable' (/Users/gui_talarico/dev/repos/gtalarico/test/project/airtable.py)
```